# get text of all <p> in div htmlagilitypack

Tags: .net, winforms, parsing, html-agility-pack

i have a div that which contains paragraph tags like this

```
<div class="div_5">
                <p>First Paragraph</p>
                <p>Second Paragraph</p>
                <p>Third Paragraph</p>
                <p>Fourth Paragraph</p>
 </div>
<div class="div_5">
                <p>First Paragraph</p>
                <p>Second Paragraph</p>
                <p>Third Paragraph</p>
                <p>Fourth Paragraph</p>
 </div>
```

i need to get the text of all paragrap text using htmlagiitypack i tried this,

```
Dim oPB As HAP.HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='post-bodycopy clearfix']/child::text()/"]
For Each item As HAP.HtmlNode In oPB
                    debug.print(item.InnerText)
                Next
```

the output am expecting for each div string is

```
First Paragraph
Second Paragraph
Third Paragraph
Fourth Paragraph
```

but am getting some html in the text returned, can someone help me correct the problem

Comment: If the p's contain HTML (not in your example data) the inner text will show it. What were you expecting?

Comment: yes the p's conytain html in the source, but not in the rendered text. can i not get the text inbetween the p's <p >`this text`< /p>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually select the paragraphs' inner text. Your xpath gets something else completely.

```vb
Dim query = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='div_5']/p/text()")
```

Comment: thanks, will this return all the five paragraphs combined, as this is what i need

Comment: No, in this case, it will return each of the individual text nodes (due to the inclusion of `text()`).  So based on your example, you would get a collection of 4 nodes, each with their respective inner text values (i.e., `"First Paragraph"`, `"Second Paragraph"` and so on).  You would have to combine them if you wanted a single string.

Comment: i tried you solution, but its selecting both the p's with class attrbs and those without this. i don't want to select the p's with class attribs